# Php counter in Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add special class "last" to every third post of my loop to get my columns right (I have 3 vertical columns).

I have found this bit of code on another post :

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ) ); ?>
    <?php
        $i = 1; //first value of $i
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
           if( $i % 3 == 0 ): // for every three post
             $class = 'last';
           else:
             $class = ''; 
           endif;

        ?>
    <div class="four columns <?php echo $class ?>">
        <?php the_content(); //along with other stuff in looped div ?
           $i++;
         >
    </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

It seems to be the right option for me but my problem is that my articles are displayed this way :

```
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' );  ?>>
```

That means I cannot add the `echo $class` to my lopped article, and I cannot find the correct syntax to get it right..!

Anybody ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks after 20 reputation u can chat with your issue at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65335/wordpress-and-magento-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using above case try to change

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' );  ?>>
```

to

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post '. $class );  ?>>
```

change

```
if( $i % 4 == 0 )
```

to

```
if( $i % 3 == 0 )
```

Comment: Wicked thanks a lot ! That did the trick ! But I have one little problem left : the class "last" is added to every 1rst post instead of every 3rd post :/ ... do you know why ?

Comment: You need to updated your question with actual/updated code than i will be able to check that

Comment: Ok, thanks to Ravi Patel who actually fixed my issue, it was a syntax problem, and my counter was starting at 0 instead of 1..
The corrected code above is up and runnig, hurray !